# Counter that scales randomly

Tags: javascript

I need to develop a counter that decreases by 1 every 10-20 seconds, where this interval is random.

For example: starting at 10, X seconds after the counter will be 9 seconds. After Y seconds it should be 8 seconds. When it arrives at 0, the counter should stop. How can I do this?

```
function animateValue(id) {
 
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var counter = getLocalStoregaValue();
  var current = counter ? +counter : obj.innerHTML;
 
  obj.innerHTML = counter;
 
  setInterval(function() {
      var counter = current--;
      obj.innerHTML = counter;
      localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
  }, 1000);

}

function getLocalStoregaValue() {
  return localStorage.getItem('counter');
}

animateValue('value');
```

Comment: How can i what ? Whats your expected output.

Comment: I would like it to drop randomly. 10 to 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to continuous invoke the function.

```
function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var counter = getLocalStoregaValue();
  var current = counter ? +counter : +obj.innerHTML;
  obj.innerHTML = counter;
  function decrement(){
    --current;
    obj.innerHTML= current;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
    if(current != 0){
        setTimeout(decrement, (Math.floor(Math.random()*11) + 10) * 1000);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(decrement, (Math.floor(Math.random()*11) + 10) * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much hev1. Unfortunately, it doesn't work:
https://jsfiddle.net/jp39x7ef/
https://jsfiddle.net/hjzxsyqL/

Comment: @FilippoCaruso It does work: https://jsfiddle.net/o3ascypg/3/

Comment: yes, now it works properly but without localstorage :(
It always restarts from the number in html

Comment: Now it's perfect :) Thank you hev1

Comment: @FilippoCaruso Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use async - await.

```
 function customDelay(ms) {
   return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
 }

async function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var counter =  10; // getLocalStoregaValue();
  obj.innerHTML = counter;
  var delay;
  while (counter > 0) {
    delay = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) * 1000;
    console.log('random delay: ', delay);
    await customDelay(delay);
    counter--;
    obj.innerHTML = counter  
  }
}

animateValue('value');
```

Initial counter is set to 10 (Or just read it from the storage like before).
In the while-loop:

- get a new random delay (between 1 and 10 seconds (1000-10000ms))
- await this time
- proceed with subtracting from counter

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/brandtCodes/epf8v3c4/33/

And with local storage:
https://jsfiddle.net/brandtCodes/epf8v3c4/39/

Comment: yes, now it works properly but without localstorage. can i solve somehow?

Comment: sure. Here we go: https://jsfiddle.net/brandtCodes/epf8v3c4/39/